# Database tables relationship in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a jobs(job) table and a tool table in my database. Tool table is divided in two parts first is category(tool_category) and other is tool data(common_tools).

Now what I want to ask is, I have a job form in which I have to select some dropdown fields which are listed from tools(common_tools) for different categories(tool_category). I am giving two approaches below. Please suggest which one is better and why.

**Approach 1**

I have created a table "tools_in_jobs" which contains three fields and we can know with this that which tool value is selected for which category in job form.

[image]

**Approach 2**

Another approach is instead of a common tables for all tools we can create separate table for each tool like shown in below diagram. But one thing to note here is that these two tables (job_faculty and job_expertise) are just for example there could be 5 to6 such tables as I am using 5 to 6 tools from different category.

[image]

Please also suggest if there is any other suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really understand what you are trying to accomplish, but what I can say is that approach 2 isn't good at all. A table for each tool? Which all have the same fields? Na! This is a huge overhead and is comparable to "duplicated code" in a program. Maintainability, expandability, etc. are also really bad I think.

Then to approach one - I don't get why the "tools_in_job" table has a relationship to tools AND to categories - wouldn't the one to the tools be enough?(It looks like a useless redundance) Or what is the meaning of this category?

As I said you really need to give a better explanation for what you're trying to accomplish. I will edit then.

Comment: yes you are right we can remove the tool_category_id from tools_in_job table as it is already related with common_tools and that in turn related with category. Thanks for your reply because I got my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Approach 1 is the preferred approach but remove tool_category_id from job and also the relationship between tools_in_job and tool_category to normalise the design.

Approach 2 would mean creating a new table every time you add a new tool, writing and maintaining more code, maintaining more tables and indexes and would use more storage.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have already made these changes after tenhouse's suggestion.